# Hibernate Error: Duplicate collection role mapping

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I used hibernate to reverse-engineer a few mySQL tables, linked with foreign keys to the `ID` field. Now I'm getting `org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate collection role mapping com.hibernate.user.User.empHours.` I have solved this issue before fiddling around with my code but I had to redo the reverse engineering and can't seem to get rid of the error this time. If someone could explain how to solve the issue and what's going on so I can understand how to fix it in the future, it would be greatly appreciated.

User info .hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- 
    Mapping file autogenerated by MyEclipse Persistence Tools
-->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.hibernate.user.User" table="user" catalog="secondsql">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ID" length="10" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Username" length="20" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Password" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="firstName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FirstName" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="LastName" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="resume" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Resume" length="100" />
        </property>
        <property name="admin" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="admin" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="colorScheme" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="colorScheme" length="10" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="empHours" inverse="true" table="emp_hours">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" length="10" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.hibernate.hours.EmpHours" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

employee hours .hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- 
    Mapping file autogenerated by MyEclipse Persistence Tools
-->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.hibernate.hours.EmpHours" table="emp_hours" catalog="secondsql">
        <id name="timesheetId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="Timesheet_ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="user" class="com.hibernate.user.User" fetch="select">
            <column name="ID" length="10" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="weekOf" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="WeekOf" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="workType" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Work_Type" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="monday" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Monday" />
        </property>
        <property name="tuesday" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Tuesday" />
        </property>
        <property name="wednesday" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Wednesday" />
        </property>
        <property name="thursday" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Thursday" />
        </property>
        <property name="friday" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Friday" />
        </property>
        <property name="saturday" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Saturday" />
        </property>
        <property name="sunday" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Sunday" />
        </property>
        <property name="weekTotal" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Week_Total" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The thing I find interesting about the error is that empHours is in `com.hibernate.hours` and user info is in `com.hibernate.user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody stumbles upon this, I solved the issue by just using annotation mappings rather than `.hbm.xml` it's much simpler to use.

Comment: with hibernate 4, using annotation mapping is as simple as replacing <mapping class=... by <mapping package=..